# calculate expected value - tossing 4 coins ...

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

In four tosses of coin, let $x$ be the no. of heads. Tabulate the $16$ possible outcomes with the corresponding values of $X$. Derive the probability distribution of $X$ and calculate $E(2 X+1)^{\wedge} 2 ?$

I have learned Statistics, but unable to solve this question. can anyone help?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) is an important part of [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/42969)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is the number of heads in $4$ tosses of a coin, we can have $X = 0$, $X = 1$, $X = 2$, $X = 3$, or $X = 4$. Assuming that the tosses are independent, $X$ will have a binomial distribution, $\text{Bin}\left(4,\frac{1}{2}\right)$. This means \begin{align*}&P(X=0)=\binom{4}{0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{4-0} = \frac{1}{16}, \\ &P(X=1)=\binom{4}{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{4-1} = \frac{1}{4}, \\ &P(X=2) = \binom{4}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{4-2} = \frac{3}{8}, \\ &P(X=3) = \binom{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{4-3} = \frac{1}{4}, \text{ and} \\ &P(X=4) = \binom{4}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{4-4} = \frac{1}{16}\end{align*} It follows that \begin{align*}E\left((2X+1)^2\right) &= (1^2)\left(\frac{1}{16}\right)+(3^2)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+(5^2)\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)+(7^2)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+(9^2)\left(\frac{1}{16}\right) \\ &= 29\end{align*}